# Stuck in login screen after 15.04 upgrade

Tags: upgrade, login, 15.04

I have upgraded from 14.10 to 15.04 and when I boot I get to the usual login screen but it is displayed in low resolution. When I login it briefly displays a console message then returns to the login screen. This is the case for all users and for each of the Ubuntu versions except console mode which opens a 'terminal'. 
I have tried a few things found on the help boards but without joy. 
The display manager is lightdm.
I have tried mount - of remount, rw / sequence without joy. 
Getting a bit desperate! Have a feeling it isn't mounting all the partitions (just a hunch after running blkid). 
Any suggestions welcome! (having to do this on my phone). 
Cheers Nevil

Answer (score 0):

You can login via the command line from the login screen by hitting Ctrl+Alt+F1
You can get back to the GUI with Ctrl+Alt+F7
This might make it easier to troubleshoot the problem.

The last time I had this issue I moved all of the hidden files out of my user account into a temp folder and it fixed the problem. Then I started copying them back in until I found which one was causing the problem. I think it was something in ~/.gconf

Comment: Thanks. How did you move all the hidden files to a temporary folder?

Comment: use `mkdir temporary` to make a directory called temporary. Then use `ls -a` to list all files/directories, including the hidden ones (starting with a dot, e.g. `.profile`), then use `mv -i -v file temporary` to move file to temporary (do not forget the dot). the `-i` will prompt you in case you are trying to overwrite an existing file of the same name, and `-v` will simply give you a feedback of the moving ( e.g. `'file' -> 'temporary/file'`). For moving all dotted files, use `mv .[A-z0-9]* temporary`